Smallest singular value of triangular matrix with constant rows
Suppose I have a lower-triangular $d\times d$ matrix $A_d$ where $k$'th row has the following values
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}(\underbrace{1, 1, 1, \ldots, 1}_{k}, 0, 0, 0)$$
What is the smallest singular value of $A_d$ when  $d$ is large? Empirically it appears to be approximately:
$$\sigma_\text{min}(A_d)\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{d}}$$
Is there a theoretical explanation of this?
Empirical fit for larger values of $d$:

Related observations:

largest singular value of $A_d$ grows as $O(\sqrt{d}): $post
k'th singular value of $A_d$ appears to decay as $O(1/k)$  (unanswered): post
Smallest singular value of some random matrix variables is $O(1/\sqrt{d})$ , Section 5 of Terry Tao's blogpost  and Theorem 2.7.8 of his book

Notebook

Have you computed the corresponding right singular vectors? I would guess they are taking advantage of some potential cancellations between the lower rows, so I'd guess that their entries are alternating in sign and concentrated towards the bottom, or something like that.

Are you asking about a specific matrix? The matrix $(1,..,1)^T (1,0,...,0)$ satisfies the stated conditions but the minimum singular value is zero.

@QiaochuYuan yes, the entries are alternating in sign, and getting larger towards the bottom

@copper.hat I can see now that my statement of conditions was imprecise, fixed

I don't know if this helps much, but $(A_d^T A_d)^{-1}$ is tridiagonal with a nice form.

The smallest singular value of $A_d$ is in fact on the order of $\frac1{2\sqrt d}$.
We first compute the inverse:
$$A_d^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1&\sqrt2\\&-\sqrt2&\sqrt3\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&-\sqrt{d-1}&\sqrt d\end{pmatrix}.$$
The smallest singular value of $A_d$ is the reciprocal of the largest of $A_d^{-1}$, which is the operator norm. So, we wish to maximize
$$v_1^2+\sum_{i=2}^d(v_i\sqrt i-v_{i-1}\sqrt{i-1})^2$$
subject to $v_1^2+\cdots+v_d^2=1$. Define $w_i=(-1)^iv_i\sqrt i$, so that we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{w_i^2}i=1$$
and wish to maximize
$$f(w)=2w_1^2+2w_2^2+\cdots+2w_{d-1}^2+w_d^2+2w_1w_2+\cdots+2w_{d-1}w_d.$$
If the maximum of $f(w)$ is $\sigma^2$, then $\sigma^{-1}$ is the smallest singular value of $A_d$.
On one hand, the fact that $w_1^2+\cdots+w_d^2\leq d$ gives us the bound
$$f(w)\leq 2(w_1^2+\cdots+w_d^2)+(w_1^2+w_2^2)+\cdots+(w_{d-1}^2+w_d^2)\leq 4d,$$
so $\sigma^2\leq 4d$ and thus $\sigma^{-1}\geq\frac1{2\sqrt d}$. On the other hand,  we can choose a parameter $k$ and let $w_d=\cdots=w_{d-k+1}=\mu$ for
$$\mu^2=\frac1{\frac1d+\cdots+\frac1{d-k+1}}.$$
This gives us
$$f(w)=\mu^2(4k-3)=\frac{4k-3}{\frac1d+\cdots+\frac1{d-k+1}}\geq\frac{(4k-3)(d-k)}k.$$
Taking $k$ to grow in such a way that $k=\omega(1)$ and $k=o(d)$ gives that $f(w)=4d(1-o(1))$, and so $\sigma^2\geq 4d(1-o(1))$. This means $\sigma^{-1}\leq \frac{1+o(1)}{2\sqrt d}$.

The last lower bound can also be directly maximized as $4d-4\sqrt{3d}+3$
